# State is not changing in onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I have `state` like below.

```
state = { photostatus: 'input' }
```

I have a function like below

```
changeAddress = () => { 
    this.setState({ photostatus: 'bar' }, () => {
        //some code
    });
}
```

I have another function like below

```
image_element = () => {
    console.log(this.state.photostatus);    // I am not getting `bar` here 

    if (this.state.photostatus === 'input') {
        <div onClick = { this.changeAddress }>Hello</div>
    }
}
```

I am passing `image_element` to another component like this

```
<AddAddressForm
    image_element = { this.image_element }
/>
```

My state is not changing while I click on `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
<AddAddressForm image_element = {() => this.image_element()}/>
```

Or bind function in `constructor()`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.image_element= this.image_element.bind(this)
 }
```